# Trying to make a one-liner in C# and LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I am trying to find **the first greater or equal** key (than limit) in an ordered dictionary and to return its value.

```
    public string foo(int limit, Dictionary<int, string> dir)
    {
        int index = dir.Keys.FirstOrDefault(x => x >= limit);
        return index == 0 ? dir[dir.Keys.Max()] : dir[index];
    }
```

This works. But it's ugly as hell :D

Do you have an idea how to make it in a clever, simple and pretty way? Maybe something magic with ?? operator when nothing matches the condition? But how? :D

Comment: Is it an OrderedDictionary or normal KeyValuePair Dictionary?

Comment: Consider that the more you try to cram into one line in linq, the harder it is for others to read and maintain. I would say the one liners for this particular case are fine, but I don't think what you have is ugly as hell and it is easy to read and understand the intent. All except the function name, that is.

Comment: This smells a lot like [CodeGolf.SE]. Maybe it would be okay for [CodeReview.SE], but I'd check the help section of whether it was on-topic.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan This is likely to be considered "example code" on Code Review and therefore off-topic, and this is not the types of questions that Code Golf deals with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the type of the values are nullable, then you can use:

```
return dir.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key >= limit).Value ??  
       dir.LastOrDefault().Value;
```

Since  the `KeyValuePair<int, string>` is struct (value type) and `string` is nullable, then default will return a key of `0` with a value of `null`.

***P.S:*** I suggested that your dictionary is normal `KeyValuePair` dictionary, because of the parameters of your method.

Comment: @dotctor No. It will not. `KeyValuePair` is struct.

Comment: @dotctor It won't, as `KeyValuePair<,>` is a value type - default will return a key of `0` with a value `null`

Comment: Please keep in mind - while correct - this "clever" code might get you into trouble later on. Personally I would opt for readability instead.

Comment: @BrokenGlass Do you mean, he might change the types of the keys or values?

Comment: For example - I wouldn't do this in a one liner - old fashioned code is sometimes better - either way I upvoted your answer, because this is what OP was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, as you say, the Dictionary is ordered then the whole thing could be reduced to:

```
var first = dir.Where(p => p.Key >= limit)
    .Select(p => p.Value).FirstOrDefault() ?? dir.Last().Value
```

Though the order of Dictionary is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

```
return dir.Keys.Any(k => k >= limit) ? dir.First(x => x.Key >= limit).Value 
                                     : dir[dir.Keys.Max()];
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.  Code only answers are usually not very useful unless they explain what they do.  This is very true of long segments of code.  Please consider adding an explanation of what you changed or wrote.